# Multiple Photos/Assets in one upload entry

Tags: assets, entry, upload

I'm having a bit of a problem with using craft currently. My site has a gallery section where I would like to mass-upload image files to an entry which is in the area:

admin/entries/photos

However, when I upload the files in the following fashion, by selecting all of the images, uploading them and then inserting them into the photo entry, the desired effect is not found.

[image: I Upload all of the images and select them in the interface]

[image: I then am met with this screen, with all of the images I selected in one section.]
[image: However, only the first image from the upload stack is shown on the live page.]

1. I upload all of the images and select them in the interface
2. I then am met with this screen, with all of the images I selected in one section.
3. However, only the first image from the upload stack is shown on the live page. (The last screenshot is confusing, I have uploaded those photos one by one, the photos I tried to mass up load have not worked.)

I hope this is understandable, I do not want to upload 100++ images one by one when I only need the simple functionality of a gallery. Please feel free to ask me questions.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is here. So you have added in your assets (by the looks of the screenshot they are all in there fine), and the issue comes with how that looks on the front-end? If so then it will be a problem with your template code, please can you update your answer with the code you are using so we can take a look?

Comment: Sorry @JamieWade let me explain. The images you see in my screenshot on the front end are ones that I have uploaded one by one AS WELL AS my ATTEMPT of the mass upload. If i mass upload them, only the first one of the image stack is shown. Sorry for the confusion, bad screenshotting.

Comment: Hmm ok, to me sounds more like a bug than something we can help you out with here at the Stack Exchange. If no-one comes back with any help, I'd recommend submitting a bug report directly to Craft: support@pixelandtonic.com

Comment: So you're saying mass uploaded images appear in the CP's Edit Entry form just fine (second screenshot), but they don't make it through to the front end?

Comment: CP and front end should be consistent (with the right template code that is)!

Comment: That's correct @carlcs only the first image displays as if it was the only image to be uploaded.

Comment: I'd file a bug report to P&T directly from your dashboard (to include all necessary data). You're not talking Live Preview, but properly saved entries and the images are still there if you open that entry in the CP again.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the user has created [another, better worded question](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/8845/uploaded-photos-not-showing-on-entry) for the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forget about the front-end for a moment... That would be a separate, unrelated issue.

When you mass-upload, do all files appear on the back-end (screenshot #2)? And then when you hit "Save", are all of those assets saved?

If the answer to either of those questions is **no**, then you should file a bug report. Use the "Get Help" widget on your Dashboard, and be sure to include your logs, database export, and files.

If the answer to both of those questions is **yes**, then the problem is not with your file upload. The problem is somewhere in your template. In that case, please [post a new question](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) to ask why your template isn't showing all of your uploaded images.