# Uploaded photos not showing on entry

Tags: assets, upload

Please refer [to this thread](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/8821/multiple-photos-assets-in-one-upload-entry/8837#8837) for information leading up to this problem.

I am having problems with mass file uploads, the files will upload in my CP for craft, and be present on the assets list, however when I come to post the entry, only one image will show on my live page.

Here is my code:

```
{% extends "_layout/_layout" %}

{% set bodyClass = "photos" %}

{% block metaTitle %}{{ entry.title }} Photo Gallery{% endblock %}
{% block metaDescription %}{{ entry.metaDescription }}{% endblock %}

    {% block content %}
              <div class="container">
                    <div class="page-title-heading">
                        <h1>{{ entry.title }}</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="title-border"></div>

        <div class="portfolio-container">
        {{ entry.body }}

        <ul id="portfolio-items-one-fourth" class="portfolio-items-one-fourth clearfix">
            {% set photos = entry.photos %}
            {% if photos | length %}
            {% for photo in photos %}
            <li class="item photo" style="display: inline-block; opacity: 1;">
                <div class="item-content">
                    <div class="link-holder">
                        <div class="portfolio-item-holder">
                            <div class="portfolio-item-hover-content">
                                {% set image = photo.uploadPhoto.first() %}
                                <a href="{{ image.getUrl('photoLightbox') }}" class="fancybox" rel="gallery" title="{{ photo.photoCaption }}">
                                    <img src="{{ image.getUrl('photoListing') }}" width="270" class="portfolio-img">
                                </a>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </li>
            {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        </ul>
    </div>

    <p class="next-prev gallery-links">
        {% set prev = entry.getPrev({'section' : entry.section.handle}) %}
        {% set next = entry.getNext({'section' : entry.section.handle}) %}
        {% if prev %}<a href="{{ prev.url }}">&laquo; {{ prev }}</a>{% endif %}
        {% if next %}<a href="{{ next.url }}">{{ next }} &raquo;</a>{% endif %}
    </p>
    <p class="photo-credits gallery-links">
        <a href="/photo-credits">Photographer credits</a>.
    </p>

    {% endblock %}
```

Any help with rectifying this code would be absolutely wholeheartedly appreciated!

Thank you!

Comment: Is ```entry.photos``` a Matrix field or an Assets field?

Comment: An assets field @MatsMikkelRummelhoff

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're trying to access another asset within your assets (asset meta field).

```
{% set photos = entry.photos %}

{# Loop assets of `entry.photos` as `photo` #}
{% for photo in photos %}

    {# Get first `uploadPhoto` element within `entry.photos[nth]` #}
    {% set image = photo.uploadPhoto.first() %}
    {{ image.getUrl() }}

{% endfor %}
```

I guess that's not what you want. Check your field handles again, you probably only need to do this.

```
{% set photos = entry.photos %}

{% for photo in photos %}
    {{ photo.getUrl() }}
{% endfor %}
```

If 'uploadPhoto' is an asset source and you allow users to upload to multiple sources, but only want to loop assets from 'uploadPhoto' in your template, you would do this like so.

```
{% set photos = entry.photos.source('uploadPhoto') %}
```